# How to convert from 'cli::array<Type>^' to 'CDWordArray &'

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, c++-cli, interop, mixed-mode

My MFC code has a function:

```
SelectItems(CDWordArray & awTop);
```

I invoke this thorugh another CPP project, as:

```
array< unsigned int >^ selectedItems;  
DWORD cnt = m_handle->SelectItems(selectedItems);
```

But i get error

```
can not convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array<Type>^' to 'CDWordArray &'
```

Comment: People still use `CDWordArray`?  `std::vector` has been standard for how long now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CDWordArray` isn't likely to be compatible with a managed array, the `CObject` base class makes it murky. You'll have to create a new instance of it and copy the array elements. That's expensive, consider restructuring the code so you can use the `pin_ptr<>` class. The MSDN HowTo article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/18132394%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).  Don't cast the pointer you get from `pin_ptr<>`, that's not likely to work.